# How to test camera hardware on the Zero

Tags: wifi, camera, pi-zero

I have a raspberry pi zero and a NoIR camera and the cable to attach the two.

I followed [this tutorial](http://hackaday.com/2015/11/28/first-raspberry-pi-zero-hack-piggy-back-wifi/) (or one similiar) to add WiFi to my Zero and it works. However, when I plug the camera in, it doesn't seems to connect to the wifi. I don't have a micro HDMI adapter so I really have no idea what's going on. The only way that I connect is via SSH. I set up the OS on the SD card in my raspberry pi 3.

It seems that I can't have the camera and the WIFI functioning at the same time. How do I test if this is the case?

Is it even possible to have the camera running when the WIFI is hacked on like in the tutorial?

I've tested the actual camera on the PI3 and it works, so it may be the Zero's camera cable, how do I test if that works?

---

EDIT

As Steve points out in the comments, this could be a power issue. I've found that (when connected properly) the camera knocks out the power. So what I was experiencing before was probably the camera not being connect properly which is why it wouldn't work (duh).

So an additional question is now how do I get sufficient power to the WiFi and camera without damaging anything? What is the sufficient amount of power?

Comment: How are you powering the Pi? This sounds like a case of insufficient power.

Comment: @SteveRobillard That's what I thought too, but I'm using the same power to successfully run the camera on the PI3 with the same SD card and camera. It's out of a desktop computer. I tried right into the wall with a 5V adapter and now the light won't even go on when the camera is plugged in. Camera in -> light off. Camera out -> light on. So it does seem to be a power problem.

Comment: I tried this with multiple cables and wall adapters with the same result. Camera in -> light off. Camera out -> light on.

Comment: the light going out definitely points to a power issue. I would switch to a powered USB hub and traditional WiFi dongle, and find a way to power the light separate from the Pi. That way the Pi only has to power itself and the camera.